# Make browser aware of HttpServletRespsonse sendRedirect

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am trying to make a user registration page.

My servlet looks like this

```
 package main.com.attempt.trial.servlet;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.logging.Logger;
 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


 public class UserRegisterServlet extends HttpServlet{

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("LOGGER");
    logger.info("doGet() called");
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException{
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("LOGGER");
    String name = (String) request.getParameter("firstname");
    boolean isSuccess = true;
    logger.info("doPost() called");
    logger.info(name);
    if (isSuccess){
        response.sendRedirect("/userHomePage.html");
    }else{
        response.sendRedirect("/register.html");
    }
}
```

}

I am attempting to redirect the user to either another JSP page or back to the registration page depending on if registration is successful or not. I have the JSP pages mapped in the web.xml as follows

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>UserRegisterServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>main.com.attempt.trial.servlet.UserRegisterServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UserRegisterServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/registerUser.serv</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>UserRegisterPage</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/register.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UserRegisterPage</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/register.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>UserHomePage</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/userHomePage.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UserHomePage</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/userHomePage.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If I do send redirect to "/registerUser.serv" the doGet() method in the servlet gets called like I would expect. Tomcat does not log any errors and local_host_access_log looks the way I would expect too as far as requests.

```
 127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2014:14:45:20 -0700] "GET /register.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1576 
 127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2014:14:45:20 -0700] "GET /content/jquery-2.1.1.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - 
 127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2014:14:45:22 -0700] "POST /registerUser.serv HTTP/1.1" 302 - 
 127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2014:14:45:22 -0700] "GET /userHomePage.html HTTP/1.1" 200 433
```

So, it seems like server side everything works properly, but the browser simply does not 'know' it needs to go to another page. Also, it does not matter if I try to redirect to a JSP page, a static HTML page, or if I use relative or absolute path.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did execution arrive at the servlet, via Ajax?

Comment: When you redirect in a response to an Ajax call, the actual page doesn't redirect. The response sent in your ajax response will be the file you redirected to, however, so print out the response in a div or something and you'll see that.

Comment: So, what would be an alternative? Would using Spring's forms tag library work?

Comment: The alternative: If you want the call to the servlet to result in a redirection in the browser, don't use Ajax to make the call to the servlet.

Comment: Yup, Ajax was the issue. Just rewrote the JSP page using the forms and submit button, and everything works as expected. Thanks to  developerwjk